# How to summarise multiple vriables/items across age group at once

Tags: r, apply, summary

I have a dataframe containing over 150,000 entries. Example below:

```
ID <-    1111, 1222, 3333, 4444, 1555, 6666
V1 <-    1,     0,    1,    0,    0,     0
V2 <-    1,     0,    0,    0,    0,     1
V3 <-    0,     1,    1,    0,    0,     1
V4 <-    1,     0,    1,    1,    0,     0
AgeGr <- 15-24,24-35,15-24,35-48, 48+, 35-48
```

All the variables (V1-V4 in the example) are dichotomous questions answered in 0/1. Now I would like to summarise all the occurrence of 0/1 of every variable across age groups. I expect output like this:

```
Variable       V1      V2      V3      V4    # Variale names
Answer        0  1    0  1    0  1    0  1   # answer levels (1/0)
15-24         0  2    1  1    1  1    0  2   # the frequency of "0" and "1" under this age group
24-35         1  0    1  0    0  1    1  0   
35-48         2  0    1  1    1  1    0  1
48+           1  0    1  0    1  0    1  0
```

I have tried janitor::tabyl, using tabyl(df,AgeGr, V1). Yet it only summarises the V1 in one line.
When I tried tabyl(df,AgeGr, df[,V1:V4]), it failed. I am wondering if I could go with tabyl() and use functions like apply()? or should I turn to something else?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
ID <-    c(1111, 1222, 3333, 4444, 1555, 6666)
V1 <-    c(1,     0,    1,    0,    0,     0)
V2 <-    c(1,     0,    0,    0,    0,     1)
V3 <-    c(0,     1,    1,    0,    0,     1)
V4 <-    c(1,     0,    1,    1,    0,     0)
AgeGr <- c("15-24","24-35","15-24","35-48", "48+", "35-48")

df <- data.frame(ID=ID,V1=V1,V2=V2,V3=V3,V4=V4,AgeGr = AgeGr, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ageAnswerSplit <- split(df[,c("V1","V2","V3","V4")],df[["AgeGr"]])

summarized <- do.call("rbind",lapply(ageAnswerSplit, function(answerdf) {
  answertables <- lapply(names(answerdf), function(nam) {
    at <- table(answerdf[[nam]])
    setNames(data.frame(unname(at["0"]),unname(at["1"])),paste0(nam,":",c(0,1)))
  })
  do.call("cbind",answertables)
}))
summarized[is.na(summarized)] <- 0
```

resulting in

```
> summarized
      V1:0 V1:1 V2:0 V2:1 V3:0 V3:1 V4:0 V4:1
15-24    0    2    1    1    1    1    0    2
24-35    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    0
35-48    2    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
48+      1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like a decent solution :) It worked quite well on my df.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` option -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('V')) %>%
  count(AgeGr, name, value) %>%
  unite(col, name, value) %>%
  arrange(col) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

#  AgeGr  V1_0  V1_1  V2_0  V2_1  V3_0  V3_1  V4_0  V4_1
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 24-35     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
#2 35-48     2     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
#3 48+       1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
#4 15-24     0     2     1     1     1     1     0     2
```